# Disable Plugin for specific User Role (Contributor & Subscriber)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to disable a specific plug in (Woocommerce Pay per Post) based on User Roles.

I have three types of User Roles.

1. Vendor
2. Contributor
3. Admin

My goal is IF the user is CONTRIBUTOR, the said plugin (Woocommerce Pay per Post) will be disable.

ELSE (ADMIN & VENDOR), activate plugin.

I've written this code:

```
// Disable Plugins to specific user

add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_logged_in_plugin' );

function disable_logged_in_plugin( $plugins ) {

// The 'option_active_plugins' hook occurs before any user information get generated,
// so we need to require this file early to be able to check for logged in status
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');

// If we are logged in, and NOT an admin...
if ( current_user_can('Contributor') ) {

    // Use the plugin folder and main file name here.
    // is used here as an example
       $plugins_not_needed = array ('/woocommerce-pay-per-post/woocommerce-pay-per-post.php');
        foreach ( $plugins_not_needed as $plugin ) {
            $key = array_search( $plugin, $plugins );
            if ( false !== $key ) {
                unset( $plugins[ $key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $plugins;
}
```

The problem is it's not working? User assigned to role 'Contributor' still managed to use the said plug in...

Any idea to make it work? Appreciate your help on this.

Here's the screenshot of that plugin folder and its content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm `disable_logged_in_plugin` is actually executing and that you're using a must-use plugin for this?

Comment: no, its not executing.

Comment: There's a couple of problems with your code that I started to write a response to, but then I realized I'm not actually sure what you are trying to do. By default, users in those roles shouldn't be able to see the plugin list to start with, so I don't think you are trying to _hide_ the plugin, right? Instead, you don't want its features to be used? The code path you are going down right now is a global one. If you alter the `$plugins` array and return it, that will be saved to the database for everyone, including admins. Are you trying to hide it in the menus?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I have modified my question to describe what my goal is. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @BenDaggers. Plugins are either active or not, there really isn't a "conditionally active mode". All plugins get booted very early by a call to [`wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins/) and that is a non-filterable call and "un-booting" a plugin isn't a WordPress concept. Instead, I really think you want to limit access to the features of that plugin, right?

Comment: That is correct! It's just, I don't want the CONTRIBUTOR Users to use that specific woocommerce plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing that really depends on the plugin and it is best to go to the plugin author. Some plugins check very early on for "is logged in user allowed to do XYZ" but I"m not seeing anything like that in this specific plugin. It is assuming that if an administrator installed it, it should be available for everyone to use. Looking at the code, there are a bunch of actions/filters that you could try to unset but they might break things, too. I would really recommend going to the plugin author and ask how they would do this.

Comment: I'm still with @ChrisHaas in not understanding what you're trying to accomplish precisely - as in exactly what a Contributor currently sees and can do, precisely when and where, but what the Contributor won't be able to see or do etc. after you've achieved the fix you want to achieve. The specific answer or answers to that question, possibly in conjunction with a breakdown of the plugin's code, might point to several different possible solutions

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work, but you can check your logged in user's role, using

```
wp_get_current_user()
```

Then you can use that role in the below section as parameter of current_user_can(). And it seems a typo, it should be

```
contributor
```

instead of

```
Contributor
```

So changing this area might help you

```
if ( current_user_can('contributor') ) {
```

Comment: the `wp_get_current_user` (and `current_user_can`) functions are not be available at the time the needed `option_active_plugins` runs. A user is defined AFTER the first call to the `option_active_plugins` runs. How would you solve that issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by deactivating the plugin for that user role.

```
function deactivate_wppp_based_on_role() {
    global $current_user;
    if (in_array('contributor', $current_user->roles)) {
        deactivate_plugins( '/woocommerce-pay-per-post/woocommerce-pay-per-post.php' );
    } else { 
        activate_plugins( '/woocommerce-pay-per-post/woocommerce-pay-per-post.php' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'deactivate_wppp_based_on_role');
```

Or, if you don't mind using a plugin, you can try the 'plugin organizer' plugin which supports deactivating plugins based on user roles. https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/

Go to the Plugin Organizer settings page and check the box next to each of the roles you want to be able to disable/enable plugins with. Then a separate container will appear on the post edit screen for you to disable/enable plugins with.

Comment: I don't believe the author meant to say "deactivate" based on their question. It sounds like they intended to "prevent from loading". Subtle, but huge difference, because if you're constantly "activating" and "deactivating" you're setting yourself up for major issues.

Comment: I think your suggestion of "Plugin Organizer" is worth looking into, but again they even note "WARNING: Reordering or disabling plugins can have catastrophic affects on your site. It can cause issues with plugins and can render your site inaccessible.". Which probably going to be more trouble than it's worth :( Which is what I touched on in my answer, but I still think it's a cool plugin for non-production environments. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: 95% of the time, I don't think there will be a problem. Most plugins don't do anything on deactivation. Major changes are initiated on uninstall, not deactivation. If it's something you are worried about, you can 'silently' deactivate a plugin which prevents calling deactivation hooks. By default, the parameter is set to false, but you can call ```deactivate_plugins``` like so to make it silent. 
```deactivate_plugins( '/woocommerce-pay-per-post/woocommerce-pay-per-post.php', true);```

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend this is something that should be done on a regular basis, I just think in this scenario, considering this is an addon plugin with limited functionality, and the user role is unique and specific, it's probably safe to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're going to run into is the fact that the code which validates a user is "pluggable" and does not execute until after all the plugins are loaded. So if you want to prevent a plugin from loading you need to put it in a must-use plugin. However, the `option_active_plugins` filter (the one that executes from WordPress to determine if a plugin should be loaded or not) happens BEFORE pluggable functions. Thus, you have no way of knowing who that user is to prevent the plugin from loading.

In other words

1. Must Use plugins get loaded
2. WordPress checks to see which plugins should load with the `option_active_plugins` filter
3. (Regular, Non-Must-Use) Plugins that are returned from the `option_active_plugins` filter get loaded
4. Pluggable functions (like `wp_set_current_user`) get loaded
5. User is validated

So...

The first thing you need to do is put your code in a must-use plugin. That's the good news. The bad news is you'll need to find a way to validate the user in your own way. It has to be a hack of some sort, you don't have much choice in the matter. You could try to create a PHP SESSION that stores the user info (or just capability, etc). And you need to sync that with WordPress every time the user changes. Then you must validate that PHP SESSION against the pluggable user functions once they load. A sanity check should be used to make sure they're the same, if not throw an error.

Another option as noted by @ChrisHaas is to either contact the plugin author for guidance, or go through that plugin code to see if there are any action/filters you can/want to unset. I realized neither of these two options (or my main answer) is ideal, but because WordPress allows plugins to determine how a user *could* be validated. You're stuck in a paradox.

If I was in your situation I would first try to see if using some combination of removing actions and filters (or hijacking the filters) that plugin is dependent on would be feasible. That *would* be the path of least resistance if it *could* be done.

(Also, for clarity I think you want to say you want to prevent a plugin from loading in certain situations rather than disabling it).